# Storyboard for a product pitch

Tags: website-design, information-graphics, concept-art

I've never done a storyboard/visual user story for a new app/software program before, so how would I do that? Or what are the key elements?

Basically, I need to create a storyboard of how it would affect the user's daily life.

Comment: Hi - this is a bit unclear and could do with more detail. What do you mean by "app that is undefined"? You also seem to answer yourself somewhat when you say "I need to create a storyboard of how it would impact the user's daily life."

Comment: Realistically, you can't storyboard or create a functional spec for an application that is undefined. You have to start from somewhere, and the core function, what problem it is trying to solve, of the application is where to begin so that really needs to be stated. A storyboard is an elaboration, a visual representation, of the the core functionality of the application.

Comment: One way to get started thinking about what it is is to think about what it isn't. We know it is probably not a vacuum cleaner. Probably not dog-food etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application is only an idea, you could still storyboard the key problems it might solve.

eg.

- Show Jane Salesperson happily checking her company's inventory at her desk and making a complex sale over the phone.
- Show Jane Salesperson bumping into a customer in the street, and being given an on-the-spot opportunity to double an order volume. She has to call her colleague at the office to email over a full size PDF inventory report, which she can't read easily on her iPhone, so sale goes to competitor.
- Then show how the previous scenario could have played out differently...

Comment: Focusing on the problem it would solve makes so much sense! Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Think of infomercials. If you were making an infomercial for this app, what would be the key scenes? That's your storyboard.